# Visual Studio seems corrupted: stopped stepping into and cannot clear break points

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am having a really hard time with debugging. All was working great, then suddenly it stopped working. I have a break point set on a Web API controller, which works fine. However I can no longer step into the code. I did some searching and it was suggested this sort of problem is usually related to the `.suo` file. I deleted the `.vs` folder with VS not running. I rebooted my computer too.

My understanding is that break points are stored in the `.suo` file. I used *Ransack* and did a search for `.suo` files and there are none the solution folder structure. However, after deleting and rebooting, there are still saved break points.

Also, I thought that VS would create a new `.vs` folder and `.suo` file when I start debugging. It is not.

So, I can't step into any libraries, when I could a few minutes earlier. I have saved break points but no `.suo` file (and not `.vs` folder). Any ideas where the break points are being stored? How to clean this up?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried a clean then build?

Comment: Yep. Clean and build, Rebuild, delete bin and obj folder and build...